# Geom_area unable to generate plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to make a stacked line plot with following data (referred as Test.xls):

```
Test <- read.table(text = "
  Date            A           B           C           D
1002EST 0.225164194 0.089942967 0.684289684 0.000603155
1007EST 0.606697971 0.375931286 0.015410986 0.001959757
1012EST 0.745430542 0.240069576 0.01186502  0.002634862
1017EST 0.586552052 0.253384789 0.159091468 0.000971692
1022EST 0.719846808 0.085252303 0.193054704 0.001846186
1106EST 0.908801738 0.075007121 0.015196251 0.00099489
1111EST 0.901317416 0.083624883 0.011020257 0.004037444
1116EST 0.838439325 0.116000974 0.042570946 0.002988756
1121EST 0.822848944 0.14935052  0.024948372 0.002852164
1126EST 0.878149037 0.107215826 0.011199368 0.003435768
1206EST 0.806550999 0.127171158 0.062039302 0.00423854",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I use the "import dataset" option from RStudio to import the data. And R plotting code is like below:

```
library(reshape2)
Test_melt <- melt(Test, "Date")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Test_melt, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

But I found my script did not generate any plots, which like below:
[Rplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iFgq.jpg)

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `group = variable`, and there is no need for `position = "stack"`:

```
ggplot(Test_melt, aes(Date, value)) + geom_area(aes(fill = variable, group = variable))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But what does "group" means in this sense?

Comment: It means "connect the points that belong to the same `variable`". You can use it with other geoms too, _e.g._ `geom_line`. [More details](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html).

Answer (score 2):

I offer a `tidy` approach to remove the `melt` step.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

Test %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = variable, group = variable))
```

[image]