# Stacked area chart in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I want to create a stacked area chart for the following data:

[image]

And the data continues a bit further.

I am using ggplot and tried with:

```
Dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-03-01"), Sys.Date(), "month")
ggplot(output_2, aes(x = Dates, y = ??, fill = ??)) + geom_area()
```

I do not know what to input for y and fill. I want the graph to be stacked with x1,x2,x3,x4 and a curve for x5.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geom\_area unable to generate plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008262/geom-area-unable-to-generate-plot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may helps.

## for dummy data according to image

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(-0.2510,-0.1889,-0.0440,-0.0134,0.0044,-0.0962),
  x2 = c(-0.1177,-0.1265,-0.1454,-0.2242,-0.2268,-0.1653),
  x3 = c(0.1992,0.2063,0.2026,0.2215,0.2205,0.1980),
  x4 = c(0.2316,0.2297,0.1811,0.0676,0.0656,0.1412),
  x5 = c(0.0621,0.1206,0.1943,0.0515,0.0637,0.0777)
)

dummy$date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2021-04-01"), Sys.Date(), "month")
    dummy %>%
  melt(id.vars = "date") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable, group = variable)) + 
  geom_area(colour = NA, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

## Code for your data(maybe)

```
output_2$Dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-03-01"), Sys.Date(), "month")
output_2 %>%
  melt(id.vars = "Dates") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Dates, y = value, fill = variable, group = variable)) + 
  geom_area(colour = NA, alpha = 0.5)
```